# What do you call someone with no ambition?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun to use in a description of someone who genuinely works hard and does well, but with no direction. He has no goals, and is aimless. He just doesn't know what he wants to work towards so he generally just settles for something.

Definitely not lazy. Trying to finish this sentence: "...but he certainly didn't fit the stereotype of a (....)."

Comment: You say they work hard but essentially have no desire to rise above their current position? Perhaps they are ***content***.

Comment: rudderless underachiever...sounds too lazy.

Comment: *he didn't fit the stereotype of ..* what sort of person? Someone who *doesn't* work hard? That is a different definition from someone who does. Which are you looking for?

Comment: You say you are trying to finish the sentence "....but he certainly didn't fit the stereotype of a ______".   That isn't looking for a description of the person, it is looking for a word for what the person is not.  Which do you want?   I am sympathetic to your question, because I know people like the person you are describing.  Often such people find what they are looking for, sometimes they don't.   Are you looking for a word to describe a high-school/college student, or a 40-year old person?

Comment: @ab2: I think the idea is that he is a __ who doesn't fit the stereotype of what __s are usually like.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you are looking for in a comment on bib's question. I have edited that information into your question, which is where it should be. In addition to this, I think you should edit your question to add an explanation of any words you have considered already, or found in a thesaurus.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is ***drifter***  From [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drifter)

> a person who moves from one place to another or from one job to
>   another without any real purpose

This definition is not quite right, because it overlooks the fact that a drifter might work very hard, even though he does not accumulate much, and might have a purpose that is not recognized by conventional people as a real, valid purpose.  For example, climbers often work construction jobs to earn enough money to climb. Example: Jon Krakauer, author of *Into Thin Air*, when he was young.  His purpose was to climb, climb, climb.

More generally, some people just take longer than others to find a purpose, and the process of drifting may be necessary for them to find their purpose.

Thus,

> John was a drifter, but he certainly didn't fit the stereotype of a
>   drifter

could be used of a hard-working but aimless, or seemingly aimless, person.

Answer (score -1):

There is the phrase *[spinning your wheels](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/spin-your-wheels)* which means

> to use a lot of effort without achieving anything

*Cambridge*

However, this term does not necessarily mean you have no purpose, just that your efforts are not getting you anywhere. Often one spinning his wheels really does have a goal, just not the appropriate means to get there.

Similarly, *[running in place](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+in+place)*

> Work or exert oneself without noticeable change or progress. For example, I've worked on this project for months but feel I'm running in place.

*thefreedictionary.com*

Comment: Do you think there is enough information in the original question to answer it? For example, it was tagged "noun," but this suggestion is not a noun.

Comment: @sumelic I agree it is weak and vague.

Comment: Sorry if its vague. Those help... Im looking for a noun to use in a description of someone who genuinely works hard and does well. He just doesn't know what he wants to work towards so he generally just settles for something. Definitely not lazy. Trying to finish this sentence: "...but he certainly didn't fit the stereotype of a (....)."

Comment: You need to expand your question, providing more detail, or it will be closed.